# How to get current and next 2 days forecast from openweathermap

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a Weather application. I know how to fetch the current conditions, but honestly I don't know too much about `JSON`. I have no idea how to fetch he current condition and the next 2-days forecast from `OpenWeatherMap`. I've tried pretty much everything I can think of, but nothing is working. I'm trying to fetch it from Python.I really don't get how it works. If anybody could help, that would be appreciated.

```
api_address = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=6784429f5eff661309aaa5280a143f97&q="
city = input("city name :")
url=api_address+city
j_data=requests.get(url).json()
print(j_data)
{'visibility': 16093, 'coord': {'lat': 38.35, 'lon': -81.15}, 'dt': 1522040040, 'weather': [{'main': 'Clear', 'id': 800, 'icon': '01n', 'description': 'clear sky'}], 'base': 'stations', 'id': 4802333, 'clouds': {'all': 1}, 'name': 'Indore', 'main': {'temp_max': 278.15, 'temp': 276.02, 'temp_min': 274.15, 'pressure': 1026, 'humidity': 41}, 'cod': 200, 'sys': {'sunrise': 1522063106, 'type': 1, 'sunset': 1522107746, 'message': 0.0034, 'id': 3050, 'country': 'US'}, 'wind': {'deg': 110, 'speed': 4.1}}
```

Comment: The URL you are using in the example above will give you the current weather for the specified city. Forecast for the upcoming 5 days can will be available from this [URL](http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,us&mode=xml&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22) for example. It is in a 3 hour format for every day. You will have to use a combination of both for your current objective

Comment: Thus, you should replace `weather` with `forecast` in your `api_address` (which technically makes it part of the api call, rather than the api address).

Comment: This Openweathemap api gives next 5 days information but I want forecast information for next two days only not next 5 days.

Comment: There is no api call for that. You have to post-process the response and keep onluy the data you are interested in.